# How to determine if a device with a specific token is online with firebase android?

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I was wondering how it is possible to determine if a device with token 'A' is online with another android device using firebase framework?

Answer (score 1):

When app starts, you can use https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/ondisconnect/remove.html to make sure that a specific data is removed when client comes offline. Then you can, somewhere else, see if that data is there (still online) or not (now offline).

This page https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/ondisconnect/ states the following

> The onDisconnect class allows you to write or clear data when your
>   client disconnects from the Firebase servers. These updates occur
>   whether your client disconnects cleanly or not, so you can rely on
>   them to clean up data even if a connection is dropped or a client
>   crashes.
>
> The onDisconnect class is most commonly used to manage presence in
>   applications where it is useful to detect how many clients are
>   connected and when other clients disconnect. See Offline Capabilities
>   for more information.

Let´s say you have a list of online users in your db. Something like this:

```
onlineUsers: {
  user1: true,
  user23: true,
  user100: true
}
```

The example illustrates that users user1, user23 and user100 are online. Let´s say user23 comes online and you want the firebase db to reflect if that user is online or not, do this:

```
var disconnectRef = new Firebase('https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio-demo.com/onlineUsers/user23');
disconnectRef.onDisconnect().remove();
```

The above code does not remove anything at execution. It just tells the Firebase server to remove onlineUsers/user23 when client comes offline.

As soon as that client (say Android app/device) comes offline, the Firebase servers will make sure that the new state will be like this:

```
onlineUsers: {
  user1: true,
  user100: true
}
```

As you can see, user23 is no longer present in the list.

Comment: But I think this is the `safe way of doing things`. What if network goes down suddenly? Will this event handler do its job?

Comment: Also I think this is for the database operations which I am not working with, but thanks again for your answer

Comment: Yes, it is the safe thing to do. Even on disconnects. I edited my answer and provided some more information.

Comment: this got interesting. You mean I can for example call a HTTP post request in `OnDisconnect` method? For example to call a method in my server that changes the status?

Comment: All the information I am seeing is for the database. Even the `OnDisconnect` class is for when a user disconnects from the SERVER.
I should be able to run the code in my client app first. Can you give me a code example of what you have in mind in android?

Comment: I am not 100% I understand you. But I will try to explain anyway: You can use the Firebase db to see if a specific user is still online. It will work even if user suddenly kills the app in the phone or closes the web browser, or the power suddenly goes out etc. It works by telling the Firebase servers what you want to be done, in case of a client going offline. It could for example be to clear a value on the database - indicating the user is no longer online. So, in short, when user comes online, use one of the onDisconnect-methods to make sure that a flag in the db is cleared (remove()).

Comment: is `OnDisconnect` class a server-side class or a client side calss? I mean where should I call it? In the server side or in the android client application?

Comment: It should be called on the Android app (or other app or web app). I added an example in the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114159/discussion-between-roostaamir-and-sten).